# Use typeahead bootstrap with Elasticsearch

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, meteor, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to implement this with elasticsearch and it is working But how i can force to typeahead class show results which can be different from the searched terms? 
For example i search ardino, The elasticsearch give me the word arduino but then typeahead does not show that result because ardino does not contain arduino. I know the idea of this library is exactly that and it is working ok and probably is overpower to do what i want, but i have most of the things already implemented and it is only missing that part.

The handle is giving the right behavior and it is populating the options correctly. 
Thank you

```
<Fragment>
              <Typeahead
              {...props}
                {...this.state}
                inputProps={{
                  autoCorrect: 'off', // Safari-only
                  spellCheck: false,
                }}
                labelKey="name"
                minLength={1}
                selectHintOnEnter={true}
                onInputChange={this._handleSearch}
                placeholder="Search for a ..."
                onChange = {(val) => {
                  this._handleSearch(val[0])
                }}
                maxResults = {5}
                renderMenuItemChildren={(option) => (
                  console.log(option),
            <div>
              {option}
              <div>
                <small>Capital: {option}</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
              />
              <SearchResults results={ this.state.results } />
        </Fragment>
```